# Numpy reshape yields a different size error

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I have a piece of Python code which has been used for about a year without any issues (it reads, uncompresses/unpacks data, selects a window and plots it using Numpy/Matplotplib).

We recently got a new machine which stores the data in a 64-bit encoded format instead of a 32-bit encoding which should not be a real issue. I rewrote a few lines of the code to deal with this (both functions of interest are included below) but I keep getting an error that I do not quite understand.

**The Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./3D_Visualizer.py", line 238, in <module>

  File "./3D_Visualizer.py", line 232, in main
    main()
  File "./3D_Visualizer.py", line 93, in plot_data
    ax.set_ylabel('Time (s)',color='r')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 170, in reshape
    return _wrapit(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 37, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj),method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged
```

I would love if someone is able to explain to me why this error occurs as to my understanding the numpy reshape function takes the size of the input array for the actual resize. The code of the 2 functions which lead to this error are listed below:

**Reading function:**

```
def numpy_array(data, peaks):
    """Fills the NumPy array 'data' with m/z-intensity values acquired
    from b64 decoding and unpacking the binary string read from the 
    mzXML file, which is stored in the list 'peaks'.

    The m/z values are assumed to be ordered without validating this
    assumption.

    Note: This function is the performance bottleneck
    """
    rt_counter=0
    for x in peaks:
        if rt_counter %(len(peaks)/20) == 0:
            update_progress()
        peak_counter=0
        data_buff=base64.b64decode(x)
        endian = '!'
        precision = 'd'
        buff_size = len(data_buff) / struct.calcsize(endian + precision)
        index=0
        for y in struct.unpack(endian + precision * buff_size, data_buff[0:len(data_buff)]):
            if (index % 2 == 0):
                data[rt_counter][1][peak_counter][0]= y
            else:
                data[rt_counter][1][peak_counter][1]= y
                peak_counter+=1
            index+=1
        rt_counter+=1
```

**The plotting function:**

```
def plot_data(X,Y,Z):
    """Plots a 3D wireframe based on the x, y and z datapoints passed
    to this function in the python lists 'X', 'Y' and 'Z'. Custom 
    labels are created for the Y (m/z) axis since matplotlib creates
    'ugly' labels by default (TODO: labelling goes wrong).
    """
    fig=plt.figure()
    x=sorted(set(X))
    y=sorted(set(Y))
    labels=['%.2f'%k for k in y]
    XX,YY=np.meshgrid(y,x) 
    ZZ=np.reshape(Z,XX.shape)
    ax=fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')
    ax.plot_wireframe(XX,YY,ZZ)
    ax.set_title('3D projection of LC-MS region',size='large',color='r')
    ax.set_xlabel('m/z',color='r',style='italic')
    ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
    ax.set_ylabel('Time (s)',color='r')
    ax.set_zlabel('Intensity',color='r')
    plt.show()
```

**-- 30/07/13 2:10 --**

the X, Y and Z all have the same length in the test case that throws this error (namely 184). The length for x and y is 18 and 20 respectively after `set` lines in the error test case while they were 18 and 11 after `set` lines in the working test case.

example contents of `y` in the error case (64-bit encoded):

```
[1398.51513671875, 1398.5152587890625, 1398.5225830078125, 1398.522705078125, 1398.530029296875, 1398.5301513671875, 1398.5374755859375, 1398.53759765625, 1398.5447998046875, 1398.544921875, 1398.55224609375, 1398.5523681640625, 1398.5596923828125, 1398.559814453125, 1398.567138671875, 1398.5672607421875, 1398.5745849609375, 1398.5819091796875, 1398.58203125, 1398.58935546875]
```

example contents of 'y' in the working case (32-bit encoded):

```
[1398.51171875, 1398.5191650390625, 1398.526611328125, 1398.533935546875, 1398.5413818359375, 1398.548828125, 1398.5562744140625, 1398.5635986328125, 1398.571044921875, 1398.5784912109375, 1398.5859375]
```

This shows that in the error case the decoding has issues regarding fitting the value, I think?

**-- 31/07/13 10:20 --**

I dove back into the raw data acquired from the actual machine and it showed that the measurement coordinates are not the same for all time points (something which was the case for all previous versions of the machine + controlling software). This has the effect that certain coordinates are ever so slightly shifted a litle bit (ie 1398.5152... vs 1398.5151) causing the reshape to fail.

I am currently in the process of just assigning each coordinate to an integer value (1, 2 ...) to 'hot fix' this for now.

Comment: I'm actually surprised the lengths of 18 and 11 (x and y) work, because 18 * 11 != 184, and the reshape() call should fail. I have to assume that the length of Z is different in the working case (198 perhaps)? The origin of those different sizes will indeed be in the unpacking.

Comment: Have you compared data_buff (or part of it) for the working and the failing cases? The decoded data string should be the same, right? So that will simply tell you whether that part causes the failure.

Comment: Can you cut this down to the _minimum_ needed to generate the error?

Comment: The binary strings are too large to fit into a SO question :(

Comment: No need to put the strings into the question, but you can tell us the comparison result (or the comparison result(s) of parts of the string): are they equal?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not really an answer, but comment fields are somewhat limited:

I find the backtrace odd: it jumps from `ax.set_ylabel` to `return _wrapit(a, 'reshape', newshape, order=order)`, without any intermediate call inside matplotlib (eg, I would expect a call to `fromnumeric.reshape` from within `set_ylabel`.
The only occurence of `reshape` in your code is

```
ZZ=np.reshape
```

so perhaps the culprit is that, and somehow the order has gotten messed up in the backtrace.

```
ZZ=np.reshape(Z,XX.shape)
```

fails if `Z` and `XX` have incompatible shapes. I assume `X`, `Y` and `Z` do have compatible shapes when calling `plot_data()`. Since `XX` is created in the `meshgrid()` call, `y` or `x` may have incorrect dimensions. 
As `x` and `y` are created by calling `set()` on `X` and `Y`, this could be where things go wrong: values occurring multiple times in `X` or `Y` could mess up things, even if it all concerns floating point values.

So I would  verify the shape (length) of `X`, `Y` and `Z`, and then that of `x` and `y` as well.

I notice an

```
unpack_format=">%dL" % buff_size`
```

line which suggests the data are actually longs, not floating point (making it easier to run into the problem of values occurring multiple times). Then again, `unpack_format` is nowhere used.

Comment: `unpack_format` is a left over line from the old version, I will double check the length of the variables however.

Comment: X,Y and Z are all of the same length. x and y are expected (and should) be difference size however. The data reflects time-based measurements where X is the time and Y,Z are the actual measurement points.